# invalid value 'edge' in 'fsantize-coverage=edge' when using LLVM LibFuzzer

Tags: clang, llvm, fuzzing

http://llvm.org/docs/LibFuzzer.html
I'm doing some works with libfuzzer now but when I do with the official toy example. when i run this command:

```
clang++ -fsanitize=address -fsanitize-coverage=edge test-fuzzer.cc Fuzzer*.o
```

there is an error happening that

```
clang: error: invalid value 'edge' in 'fsanitize-coverage=edge'
```

it seems that clang supports this argument but i'm wondering how i can see what value is supported...
i installed llvm 3.6 by apt-get with unbuntu14.04...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax of the `fsanitize-coverage=` flag has been changed, as described in [this commit message](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang/commit/b8ef8e90281b9e0d159a30653bb139374d4abc52) from May 2015. This bit is particularly relevant to you:

```
Original semantics of -fsanitize-coverage flag is preserved:
  * -fsanitize-coverage=0 disables the coverage
  * -fsanitize-coverage=1 is a synonym for -fsanitize-coverage=func
  * -fsanitize-coverage=2 is a synonym for -fsanitize-coverage=bb
  * -fsanitize-coverage=3 is a synonym for -fsanitize-coverage=edge
  * -fsanitize-coverage=4 is a synonym for -fsanitize-coverage=edge,indirect-calls
```

So you might try `-fsanitize-coverage=3`.