# Invalid clang sanitizer options

Tags: c++, clang, llvm, address-sanitizer

I am using clang sanitizer with Clang.

The command below is copied from the link to the  official doc: 
http://llvm.org/releases/3.7.0/tools/clang/docs/SanitizerCoverage.html

```
$ clang++ -g cov.cc -fsanitize=address -fsanitize-coverage=bb
```

However, it gives me the error message below

```
clang-3.7: error: invalid value 'bb' in '-fsanitize-coverage=bb'
```

I changed `bb` above to `edge` or `func` but none of them work, whereas the link above says:

> ```
> SanitizerCoverage can be used with AddressSanitizer, LeakSanitizer, MemorySanitizer, and UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer. In
> ```
>
> addition to -fsanitize=, pass one of the following compile-time flags:
>
> ```
>     -fsanitize-coverage=func for function-level coverage (very fast).
>     -fsanitize-coverage=bb for basic-block-level coverage (may add up to 30% extra slowdown).
>     -fsanitize-coverage=edge for edge-level coverage (up to 40% slowdown).
> ```

I am using Ubuntu 14.

Comment: clang 3.8 seems to be happy with them. Not that that is any consolation.

Comment: However, the clang 3.7 page above does mention -fsanitize-coverage=bb  is valid option of the clang command line.

Comment: The syntax for the flag changed at some point. You can try the old style, summarized in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35436249/invalid-value-edge-in-fsantize-coverage-edge-when-using-llvm-libfuzzer/35468809#35468809

Comment: @wad voting to close as duplicate